# How do I make a div/img still centered once reaches min-width

Tags: css, scaling

Once the viewport reaches 600px, I've set the div/image to stop scaling using min-width. Basically I don't want the images to look too small on mobile and happy for them to be "cropped" on the sides, just so long the centre of the image is seen. I also don't want it to kick in exactly when ti reaches 600px with a media query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your code (HTML & CSS) in your question. A demo (i.e., CodePen) would be even better!

Answer (score 0):

You can use translateX and relative positioning.

```
min-width:600px;    
position:relative;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the css property max-width:100%; and height:auto the image will scale automatically, all you need to do is give this property to image or its class

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to help without a small example, but ...
Image is actually smart and can scale on its own.

your markup:

```
.myDiv{
  max-width: 300px; // or your other media query settings
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}
.myDiv img{
  width: inherit; // to set image width
  position:absolute; // to respond to relative
  left:-50%; // to center
}

<div class="myDiv">
    <img src="<your src here>"  />
</div>
```

Idea is to provide width to image and use relative/absolute to position it appropriately.
Use these styles for you media query